# Query performance when applying the "Great mapping refactoring"

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, elasticsearch-mapping

Our applications' entities are dynamic, we don't know how many properties they'll have or what their type will be.

Up until now, we've indexed our data in the following way:

```
{
  "message": "some string",
  "count":   1,
  "date":    "2015-06-01"
}
```

**After reading the [following blog](https://www.elastic.co/blog/great-mapping-refactoring):**

We've understood that it's better to index the data like this:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "key": "message",
      "str_val": "some_string"
    },
    {
      "key": "count",
      "int_val": 1
    },
    {
      "key": "date",
      "date_val": "2015-06-01"
    }
  ]
}
```

We were wondering how the index would work in terms of nested aggregations. 
will the mapping refactoring above damage the indexing time (and/or the query/aggregation time) due to the fact that now, every entity will be nested one level deeper?

We have thousands of different object types, hence our mapping file is huge. That slows down the indexing time, so a mapping refactoring is highly necessary.

Are you aware of any disadvantages when it comes to refactoring our mapping as explained in the blog above?

Comment: why don't you index each entity into its own index? I assume each entity has a given fixed set of properties, doesn't it?

Comment: Some of our types have a very small amount of entities. Creating a separate index for those types would be inefficient.

Comment: not necessarily, those are called administrative index (pretty much like the `.kibana` index and other indices with an initial dot). Simply assign a single shard to it and it doesn't hurt at all.

Comment: Then we would have thousands of those small indices. Wouldn't that have any affect at all?

Comment: Well, of course too many indices is not a good idea either... Anyway, it depends on what you need to do with those indices. Why are they in ES in the first place? Your use case is not easy to understand so far.

Comment: We do not have control over how many entities there are in each type. Some of the types have millions of entities and some have only a few hundreds. We need a powerful aggregation tool to use on this data and elastic does the job. We've done many experiments and right now we want to understand how this mapping refactoring process could affect us if we try it out. Aggregations are our main concern.

Comment: If you refactor as described in the article you linked to, your mapping will clearly get much smaller. However, depending on the kind of queries you need to make, they will get much more complex. There's no right or wrong, it really depend on your use cases. Maybe staying like you are now is better than refactoring, but you need to run a proof of concept with the new suggested mapping and see if your queries can be refactored as well. No one can tell if that will work out for you.

Comment: Obviously this is something that requires checking and testing and we are planning on doing a poc as you said. This refactoring is recommended by elastic but to us it seems like it could potentially slow down queries. We're asking if anyone here has done this refactoring or anything similar and can share their experience.

Comment: It is "one" (out of many) ways to alleviate the problem (if that's a problem at all). If you're not seeing any issues with your current setup so far, why change it? "if it ain't broke, don't fix it", right?